# Print mysql result 10 by 10 php css page break after

Tags: php, css, page-break

For example I have 100 result in my query.

I want to printing paper every page 10 result.

How to print php mysql query result 10 by 10 css page-break-after?

Answer (score 1):

You did not ask your question very well in English.
But I think that you can run your query like this :

```
SELECT * FROM tableName ORDER BY fieldName DESC LIMIT $startIndex, $count
```

Which `$startIndex` could be your starting number and `$count` could be 10 in your case.

**NOTE** Do not forget to edit my code and use prepared statement in your query

Comment: thx but I have no problem with the query. my problem 10 results per printer output.I want to seperate 100 result into 10pcs a4 paper.every page 10 result